# Android: How to insert subscript in the middle of the text in sqlite3 database

Tags: android, sqlite, superscript

I am populating into sqlite3 db from a text file and i have many superscript in the middle of the text.
Can anyone please let me know as what should i add in my text file, to make this work

Answer (score 0):

In the database, all TEXT fields contain plain text.

If you want to have formatting instructions, you have to encode them somehow, e.g., as HTML:

```html
some text <sub>with subscripts</sub> ...
```

or TeX:

```tex
some text \textsubscript{with subscripts} ...
```

This implies that you always have to ensure to escape special characters (like `<` or `\`).

What format to use depends on what software you use to actually format the text later (Android widgets typically support HTML).